# If $T$ is an invertible linear operator, then so is $T^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inverse-function, adjoint-operators

Suppose that $V$ is an arbitrary vector space and that $T \in L(V)$ is invertible and admits an adjoint.

> Is it true that, in this case, $T^*$ is invertible?

It is well-known that this is true in finite dimensional vector spaces, because, in those spaces, a transformation is invertible iff its injective, and $\ker(T^*) = \operatorname{Im}(T)^\perp = 0$.

But, in arbitrary ones, the equivalency falls short, and also, we can only say that $\operatorname{Im}(T^*) \subset \ker(T)^\perp$ - there are counter-examples to the other inclusion in arbitrary vector spaces.

It is easy to prove that **if** this is the case, then the adjoint's inverse will be an adjoint for the inverse of $T$ ($(T^*)^{-1} = (T^{-1})^*$), but I couldn't really prove existence before doing the algebraic manipulations...

In fact, **perhaps it would be easier to prove that $T^{-1}$ admits an adjoint**, since the result could also follow from there, but I also couldn't really move in that direction.

Does anyone have any insights as per how to proceed? Or perhaps a counter-example in infinite dimensions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @daw How can we say that $T^{-1}$ has an adjoint? For instance, the derivative operator over the space of polynomials does not have one.

Comment: You'll find a simple counter-example in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4709966/counterexample-for-adjoint-of-an-isomorphism-is-isomorphism/4710009#4710009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given vector spaces $V, W$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$, the adjoint of a linear map $T \colon V \to W$, is the linear map $T' \colon W' \to V'$ (here $V'$ denotes the space of all linear maps from $V$ to $\mathbb{F}$). defined by $\langle v, T'\omega\rangle := \langle Tv, \omega\rangle$, where for linear functional $b$, vector $a$, $\langle a, b \rangle = b(a)$. It follows easily that if $X$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ and $S \colon W \to X$ is linear, then $(ST)' = T'S'$.

Thus if $T \colon V \to V$ is an invertible linear map, then $T'(T^{-1})' = (T^{-1}T)' = I' = I_{V'}$ and $(T^{-1})'T' = (TT^{-1})' = I' = I_{V'}$. Thus $(T')^{-1} = (T^{-1})'$.

But it seems like you are asking about the adjoint when $V$ is an inner product space over $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. If $V, W$ are inner product spaces over $\mathbb{F}$, then a linear map $T \colon V \to W$ has an adjoint $T^* \colon W \to V$ means that $(v, T^*w) = (Tv, w)$ for all $v \in V, w \in W$, where $(\cdot, \cdot)$ denotes inner product. In this case, I don't think all linear maps have adjoints. But if $V$ and $W$ are Hilbert spaces and $T \colon V \to W$ is a continuous linear map, then by the Riesz representation theorem, $T$ has an adjoint. Moreover, if $T$ is invertible, then by https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem, $T^{-1}$ is continuous and therefore has an adjoint.

Comment: I’m sorry, you’re correct in your assumption - I do mean adjoint as in your last definition. But Riez’s theorem is only valid over Hilbert Spaces (according to what I’ve found). Perhaps there is a counter-example over “non-Hilbert inner product spaces”?

Comment: @Gauss Yes, the result of my analysis is that if $V$ is a complete inner product space and $T$ is a continuous linear bijection, then $T^{-1}$ has an adjoint. Thus to find counterexamples, you have to examine non complete inner product spaces or noncontinuous linear map $T$. To find a not complete inner product space, you can take a linear subspace of a complete inner space that is not closed.