# counterexample for adjoint of an isomorphism is isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators

The following question is related to the question:

> [If $T$ is an invertible linear operator, then so is $T^*$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4291996/if-t-is-an-invertible-linear-operator-then-so-is-t)

Let $V$ and $W$ be two vector spaces with scalar products and $\phi: V \to W$ be a linear map with an adjoint $\phi^*$. It is clear, that if $\phi$ and $\phi^*$ are both invertible, then $(\phi^{-1})^*=(\phi^*)^{-1}$. My question is: Does someone have an easy counter-example (to show my students) that the following implication is wrong

> $\phi$ is an isomorphism $\Rightarrow$  $\phi^*$ is an isomorphism

e.g. does someone have an isomorphism with adjoint whose inverse doesn't have an adjoint?

Comment: Given the accepted answer to the linked question (and comments on it), either $V$ has to be not complete or $T$ has to be not continuous.

Comment: yes, I was aware of that. I was trying to construct such an example with finite sequences, but couldn't come up with a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example I have found is the following:
Let $V:=\mathbb R^\mathbb N_{fin}$ be the vector space of finite sequences with the inner product

$$ (\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}):=\sum_i a_i b_i$$

Then the isomorphism

$$ \phi: V \to V,   (a_1, a_2, \dots) \mapsto (a_1, a_2+a_1, a_3+a_2, a_4+a_3, \dots, a_{i}+a_{i-1}, \dots)$$

is  invertible and has an adjoint, namely we have:

$$\begin{align*}
\phi^{-1}&: (a_1, a_2, \dots) \mapsto (a_1, a_2 -a_1, a_3-a_2+a_1, \dots, \sum_{j=1}^i (-1)^{i-j} a_j, \dots)\\
\phi^{*}&: (a_1, a_2, \dots) \mapsto (a_1+a_2, a_2 +a_3, \dots, a_i+a_{i+1}, \dots)
\end{align*}
$$
but $\phi^{-1}$ does not have an adjoint, since we would have $$(\phi^{-1})^*(1,0,0, \dots)=(1,-1,1,-1,\dots, (-1)^i, \dots) \not \in V$$
or similarly $\mathbf{e_1}=(1,0,0,\dots)$ does not have a preimage under $\phi^*$.